# How to disable Jquery mobile popup scrolling on listView?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing Jquery mobile application for IOS and Android. I prevent popup to close on click outside of it. My popup is opening on a list and when I type anything in popup textArea that popup scroll up and down according to list scroll. Even my popup scroll when my list scroll. Is there any way to prevent list scrolling or popup scrolling.